# How to create the following small color bar and include in td?

Tags: html, colors, html-table

can you please show me how to create the following color chart, it is created by individual bar and spacing. What is the best method to use, I need to insert it into a table td. Please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you want to have:

```css
.chart {
  display: block;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.color-25 {
  background: #bbb;
}

.color-50 {
  background: #777;
}

.color-75 {
  background: #333;
}

.color-100 {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart">
    <div class="bar color-100"></div>
    <div class="bar color-100"></div>
    <div class="bar color-100"></div>
    <div class="bar color-75"></div>
    <div class="bar color-75"></div>
    <div class="bar color-50"></div>
    <div class="bar color-25"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create these easily using the floating ability of CSS, for example

```css
.foo {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.blue {
  background: #13b4ff;
}

.purple {
  background: #ab3fdd;
}

.wine {
  background: #ae163e;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo blue"></div>
<div class="foo purple"></div>
<div class="foo wine"></div>
```